# LLM Q&A for large documents or several documents

Tags: nlp, openai-api, large-language-model

I need to enable a Q&A with an LLM for several documents at the time. Given the restriction on tokens for OpenAI gpt-3.5-turbo-16k what other options do I have to load multiple documents at the time (say 10 documents each one with 1000 pages) to build a QA module? Also another thing is that documents should be added on the fly (for example, a student can select 5 documents at the time to start a Q&A session)